# Why does the system generated TNSNAMES.ORA have two entires, one with a full connect descriptor and another with just a network address?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

My TNSNAMES.ORA file was auto-generated when I installed my database. It generates with two entries for my database however. One entry looks "complete" with a full connect descriptor, while the 2nd entry is just the network address of the listener.  What's the difference between the two and when would you use one versus the other?

```
DB2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = db2)
    )
  )

LISTENER_DB2 =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it generated 1 entry for the database (`DB2`), and another for the listener (`LISTENER_DB2`).

Then your `local_listener` parameter was set to `LISTENER_DB2`, so your database could use this address to find the listener and register into it, since it is not listening on the default port (1521).

Comment: Beautiful! So the "LISTENER" entry is not used by clients but rather is used by PMON for dynamic registration?

Comment: @BenFinkel Yes, but starting with 12c, it is not the PMON but the LREG background process is the one that does this.

Comment: Just as a side discussion, why do you have your listener on a non-default port?  This accomplishes nothing.

Comment: The 1Z0-072 exam tests knowledge of setting up and registering with additional listeners.